# Merge List[List[_]] conditionally

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, stream

I want to merge a `List[List[Double]]` based on the values of the elements in the inner Lists. Here's what I have so far:

```
// inner Lists are (timestamp, ID, measurement)
val data = List(List(60, 0, 3.4),  List(60, 1, 2.5),  List(120, 0, 1.1),
                List(180, 0, 5.6), List(180, 1, 4.4), List(180, 2, 6.7))

data
  .foldLeft(List[List[Double]]())(
    (ret, ll) =>

      // if this is the first list, just add it to the return val
      if (ret.isEmpty){
        List(ll)

      // if the timestamps match, add a new (ID, measurement) pair to this inner list
      } else if (ret(0)(0) == ll(0)){
        {{ret(0) :+ ll(1)} :+ ll(2)} :: ret.drop(1)

      // if this is a new timestamp, add it to the beginning of the return val
      } else {
        ll :: ret
      }
  )
```

This works, but it doesn't smell optimal to me (especially the right-additions '`:+`'). For my use case, I have a pretty big (~25,000 inner Lists) List of elements, which are themselves all length-3 Lists. At most, there will be a fourfold degeneracy, because the inner lists are `List(timestamp, ID, measurement)` groups, and there are only four unique IDs. Essentially, I want to smush together all of the measurements that have the same timestamps.

Does anyone see a more optimal way of doing this?

I actually start with a `List[Double]` of timestamps and a `List[Double]` of measurements for each of the four IDs, if there's a better way of starting from that point.

Comment: I couldn't quite follow. What exactly do you want to achieve in the end? You "want to merge" and you "want to smush", and you've scattered some fine comments throughout the code, but it's still not clear what the ultimate goal is. Do you really want `(time, id, meas, id, meas, id, meas, ...)`-lists in the end? Why do you want to have it in such an awkward format, why not model it properly as `Map[Timestamp, Map[Id, Measurement]]` or something?

Comment: Yes, I want `(time, id, meas, id, meas, id, meas, ...)` lists at the end. This way it can be easily written to a CSV and re-parsed later, if necessary.

Comment: What should happen if your input timestamps are out of order?

Comment: @Tom they're not, because I sort the list before I do any of this

Comment: In that case I would use the `groupBy` solutions provided below and you won't need to sort beforehand, which will help if your list is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly shorter way to do it:

```
data.
  groupBy(_(0)).
  mapValues(_.flatMap(_.tail)).
  toList.
  map(kv => kv._1 :: kv._2)
```

The result looks 1:1 exactly the same as what your algorithm produces:

```
List(List(180.0, 0.0, 5.6, 1.0, 4.4, 2.0, 6.7), List(120.0, 0.0, 1.1), List(60.0, 0.0, 3.4, 1.0, 2.5))
List(List(180.0, 0.0, 5.6, 1.0, 4.4, 2.0, 6.7), List(120.0, 0.0, 1.1), List(60.0, 0.0, 3.4, 1.0, 2.5))
```

Explanation:

- group by timestamp
- in the grouped values, drop the redundant timestamps, and flatten to single list
- tack the timestamp back onto the flat list of ids-&-measurements

Comment: `_.map(_.tail).flatten` can be shortened to `_.flatMap(_.tail)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility:

```
input
  .groupBy(_(0))
  .map { case (tstp, values) => tstp :: values.flatMap(_.tail) }
```

The idea is just to group inner lists by their first element and then flatten the resulting values.

which returns:

```
List(List(180.0, 0.0, 5.6, 1.0, 4.4, 2.0, 6.7), List(120.0, 0.0, 1.1), List(60.0, 0.0, 3.4, 1.0, 2.5))
```

Comment: There is a nifty method called `tail` that does exactly the same as `drop(1)`.

Comment: This needs a `toList` at the end, doesn't it? The REPL is telling me that this is an immutable.Iterable, not a List.

Comment: `groupBy` doesn't preserve the order of the keys, as it returns a `Map`. That would be the only difference between both algorithms.

Comment: @awwsmm Indeed it returns an Iterable, which can be cast as a List with toList.

Comment: @Miguel The order is lost during the groupBy.

Answer (score 1):

What about representing your measurements with a case class?

```
case class Measurement(timestamp: Int, id: Int, value: Double)

val measurementData = List(Measurement(60, 0, 3.4),  Measurement(60, 1, 2.5),  
    Measurement(120, 0, 1.1), Measurement(180, 0, 5.6), 
    Measurement(180, 1, 4.4), Measurement(180, 2, 6.7))

measurementData.foldLeft(List[Measurement]())({
    case (Nil, m) => List(m)
    case (x :: xs, m) if x.timestamp == m.timestamp => m :: xs
    case (xs, m) => m :: xs
  })
```

Comment: Good idea, but a bit too involved for what I want to do. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: That's what I would usually propose to do. But since it's all for CSV-output, the CSV format does not care about case-classes, unfortunately...